# Words to Disambiguate Alphabet Letters from Others

Tags: word-choice, spelling

Dictating e-mail/website addresses each one letter by one **on a phone call** is always challenging for me. I found that listeners often misspell certain letters like B/D/V because the pronunciation is distorted.

With a list of 26 words that represent each alphabet letter, if any, communications are going to be easier:

> I: R-A-N-D-O-M-A-L-P-H-B-E-T.
>
> Listener: (Simultaneously) R-A-N-D-O-M-A-L-P-H... wait. *D or B*?
>
> I: It's B. *B of 'black'*.

'Black' is a quick example of my own but seems good enough because 'black' is simple, easy, and there's no word such as "vlack", "dlack", "glack", etc.

I'd love the list of words like 'black' if there is already one in common use.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you are describing is called a *phonetic alphabet*.

There are a number of common phonetic alphabets used in the English language.

One of the most popular ones is the International Civil Aviation Organization (ICAO) alphabet, commonly called the NATO phonetic alphabet.  See https://wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet for a complete reference.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you didn't know to look for a *phonetic alphabet* it would have been a challenge to find what you were seeking! :-)

Comment: And even if you did you would also find the IPA (International Phonetic Alphabet), which is a system of special letters corresponding to various sounds in human languages, and completely unrelated to what you're looking for.

Comment: @JanuaryFirst-of-May raises a good point; sometimes, a distinction is made between *phonetic alphabets* like the IPA and *spelling alphabets* like the international radiotelephony spelling alphabet (the "NATO phonetic alphabet").

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I found, (phonetic alphabet) a bit blurry but you can zoom in or click the link below:

[image]

Source: http://morsecode.scphillips.com/alphabet.html

Comment: TIL Q = Quebec.

Comment: Kinda surprised the NYPD uses “Queen” for Q when [Queens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queens) must be a common thing to hear on their radios.

Answer (score 5):

There are established lists of words that stand for the first letter of the alphabet, if that is what you are wondering about. NATO uses, [Alpha, Bravo  Charlie](http://www.alphabravocharlie.info/alphabet.php).

Speakers of American English unfamiliar with this system (which is probably 95% of speakers) usually just make up a word on the spur of the moment, like "M as in Mary" or "D as in doorknob", whatever the speaker thinks will provide clarity.